# Can't INSERT new Record due to Foreign Key Issue

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql

I've seen a lot of posts about this particular error message but none seem to cover my problem. The error is :'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint'

I have set a foreign key in the table called Tests as Null as not every record will have a corresponding record in the other table called APIS.

In SSMS I can insert a new record without any issue below is my INSERT query for doing so.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tests]
       ([APIID]
       ,[ActiveID]
       ,[ABCDataID]
       ,[ReferenceNumber]
       ,[LocationAddress]
       ,[LocationPostCode]
       ,[Make]
       ,[Model]
       ,[Registration]
       ,[WPC]
       ,[IsA]
       ,[IsS]
       ,[SelfSetDate]
       ,[IsBA]
       ,[UserID]
       ,[ClaimAtFaultEnum]
       ,[ClaimADriverEnum]
       ,[XRepair]
       ,[ManRepair]
       ,[HybridRepair]
       ,[BodyType]
       ,[CustomerName]
       ,[CustomerEmail]
       ,[CustomerMobileNumber]
       ,[IsCancelled]
       ,[CancellationNote])
 VALUES
       (NULL, 
        NULL, 
       NUll,
       '111111111',
       'Waterside',
      'KA18 8EX',
       'Abarth', 
       '320',
       'TIL1607',
       NULL, 
       1,
       0, 
       NULL, 
       0,
       NUll, 
       1, 
       1, 
       0, 
       0, 
       0, 
       'Car',
       'John Smith', 
       'John@TIL1607TestData.com', 
       '07test', 
       0, 
       Null)
GO
```

Below is the same data I'm trying to put into the database using c#, it only seems to work when I set a foreign key. I can't put NULL as it's an int field and won't accept it and if I leave it out completely it comes up with the error message mentioned above.

```
    Test testToAllocate = new Test();

        if (testToAllocate != null)
        {
            int intClaimDriver = -1;
            int intClaimAtFault = -1;
            if (rdoDriverDriver.Checked)
            {
                intClaimDriver = (int)Enums.Test.Driver;
            }
            if (rdoNonDriver.Checked)
            {
                intClaimDriver = (int)Enums.Test.NonDriver;
            }
            if (rdoFaultFault.Checked)
            {
                intClaimAtFault = (int)Enums.Test.Fault;
            }
            if (rdoFaultNonFault.Checked)
            {
                intClaimAtFault = (int)Enums.Test.NonFault;
            }
            if (rdoFaultThirdParty.Checked)
            {
                intClaimAtFault = (int)Enums.Test.ThirdParty;
            }

            ABCData testToABC = db.AudaBridgeClaimDatas.Where(a => a.Registration == txtVehicleRegistration.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            if (testToAllocate != null)
            {
                testToAllocate.ABCDataID = testToABC.ABCDataID;
            }
            else
            {
                testToAllocate.ABCDataID = null;
            }


         //   testToAllocate.APIID = 5; //Needs to be Null
            testToAllocate.ReferenceNumber = "111111111"; 
            testToAllocate.LocationAddress = "Waterside";
            testToAllocate.LocationPostCode = "KA18 8EX";
            testToAllocate.Make = "Abarth";
            testToAllocate.Model = "320";
            testToAllocate.Registration = "TIL1607";
            testToAllocate.IsA = true;
            testToAllocate.IsS = false;
            testToAllocate.IsBA = false;
            testToAllocate.ClaimADriverEnum = 1;
            testToAllocate.ClaimAtFaultEnum = 1;
            testToAllocate.XRepair = false;
            testToAllocate.ManRepair = false;
            testToAllocate.HybridRepair = false;
            testToAllocate.BodyType = "Car";
            testToAllocate.CustomerName = "John Smith";
            testToAllocate.CustomerEmail = "John@TIL1607TestData.com";
            testToAllocate.CustomerMobileNumber = "07test";
            testToAllocate.IsCancelled = false; 

            db.Claims.InsertOnSubmit(testToAllocate);
            db.SubmitChanges();
```

Anyone got any ideas? It's almost as if visual studio hasn't recognized the change I made to the database to make this field null.

Comment: get generated sql code, before db.submitchanges(), and compare with your working one.

Comment: show model - class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't put NULL as it's an int field and won't accept it

Then your model doesn't reflect your database.  If your database has a nullable field, you need a nullable int: `int?`

> if I leave it out completely it comes up with the error message mentioned above

Because the model has the wrong data type for that field, and the default value for `int` is `0`.  If there's no corresponding record `0` in the target table, that's a foreign key constraint violation.

> It's almost as if visual studio hasn't recognized the change I made to the database to make this field null.

Indeed.  If you're using some tool to generate your classes from the database, re-run that tool.  If not, update your model accordingly.  You have a nullable database field and a non-nullable model field.

Basically, where on your model you have something like this:

```
public int SomeField { get; set; }
```

What you want is something like this:

```
publit int? SomeField { get; set; }
```

Then you can set `SomeField` to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have set a foreign key in the table called Tests as Null
>
> I can't put NULL as it's an int field and won't accept it

Instead of `int`, make the type `int?` ,which is a nullable int. This will allow you set the value to null.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)